# Xcode 11 GM 2 - errors when uploading

Tags: ios, xcode

Trying to upload a build made with GM seed 2 to Testflight for testing. However, I get the warning:

> ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS SDK. All iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 11 SDK or later, included in Xcode 9 or later. Further, starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later."

The confusing part is, it says my app was built with "the iOS SDK" without specifying a version number.

I am using Xcode Version 11.0 (11A420a).  I imagine this is just a small configuration change to fix, but not sure what / where to change this.

Edit:
I believe clearing the DerivedData fixed this.  I ran the following script that I had:

```
   #!/bin/bash

    killall "Xcode"
    sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
    sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.7.5
    rm -rf Pods/
    pod cache clean --all
    rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
    pod install
```

Thanks for the shout @chumps52.   Nothing like doing the Xcode equivalent of "turning it off and on again." to fix things up.

Comment: what kind of build tools do you use?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your build folder + removing all derived data? I've just uploaded a GM 2 build with no issues so I know it's not that unfortunately.

Comment: @Vyacheslav what do you mean? can you give me details?

Comment: @chumps52 yeah, i figured there would be a ton of posts if GM 2 was the issue

Comment: open xcode preference and post here 'command line tools' version here

Comment: @Vyacheslav command line tools version was already included.  it was the same as the version number build in parentheses.